# python-cant read from all rows from a csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding, utf

I am trying to read the column "Transcript Text" from a CSV file which looks like this -

```
Order,LearningID,Gender,Race,College,  ID ,B,Transcript Text
1,T66666666B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,122333444,,(BEGIN INTERVIEW)
6,T77777777B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,133333333,,INTERVIEWER:  CTVA's your major?
7,T88888888B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,144444444,,"STUDENT:  Yes, that's right."
```

And my code to read column no. 7 (Transcript text) looks like this -

```
import csv       

file_csv = open("test.csv", newline='')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
txt_string =''

common_words = ['mmhmm', 'interposing', 'xblank']

for i, v in enumerate(csv_reader):
    print (i)
    print(v[7])
    txt_string += v[7]

file_csv.close()
```

Now when I loop through this, it skips some values, not all values for v[7](column - transcript text) are printed. Curiously, the counter values don't get printed as well.

The output looks like this -

```
0
Transcript Text
3
STUDENT:  Yes, that's right.
```

I have made sure that the csv is saved using utf-8 option MS Excel, I've tried setting the encoding to utf-8 as well.

```
file_csv = open("test.csv", newline='', encoding ='utf-8')
```

But nothing works. And also very weirdly, every time I run this, the results are erratic, that is some rows that weren't previously printed get printed.

What could be the issue here?
(using Python 3.5, and the actual csv file i'm using has around 25k rows.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Can you show first 2-3 lines of you csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Python2, but worth a try to see if it fixes your problem

The first issue I see is you are giving a quote character of `|`, but it looks like your quote char should be `"` as the 8th column (Transcript Text) is wrapped in `"`, not `|`.

Also, I like to read the first row (when column headers are present) and use zip to create a dictionary of column data rather than accessing by index (which can become wrong when columns change ordering)

```
import csv

file_csv = open("so.csv")
csv_reader = csv.reader(file_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
conversation = []

common_words = ['mmhmm', 'interposing', 'xblank']

headers = [header.replace(" ", "_").lower() for header in csv_reader.next()]
for data in csv_reader:
    columns = dict(zip(headers, data))
    conversation.append(columns["transcript_text"])

file_csv.close()

for i, item in enumerate(conversation):
    print(i, item)
```

Comment: This worked, but I want to use indexes in my code as I want to filter out certain rows according to a value in some column. E.g. - if v[3] = foo then add v[7] to string. 
Also correcting the quotechar didn't correct the problem in python 3. The output is now like this - for the input "they're" the output is "they\x92re". Which means it's converting to utf implicitly through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `quotechar` is double quote `"`.
Also, starting python3 you should use this style of file handling, try it:

```
text = ''
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
csvFile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row,data in enumerate(csvFile):
    print(row, data[7])
    text += data[7]

print(text)
```

Output:

```
0 Transcript Text
1 (BEGIN INTERVIEW)
2 INTERVIEWER:  CTVA's your major?
3 STUDENT:  Yes, that's right.
Transcript Text(BEGIN INTERVIEW)INTERVIEWER:  CTVA's your major?STUDENT:  Yes, that's right.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just on the surface, it looks like you're using the wrong quotechar. From the [csv docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

> Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields
>   which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any
>   of the characters in lineterminator.

For some reason, you're passing a pipe character as the quotechar. But clearly, the data you gave is using a double-quote character, which is the default and appears to work just fine:

```
>>> import csv, StringIO
>>> data = """Order,LearningID,Gender,Race,College,  ID ,B,Transcript Text
... 1,T66666666B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,122333444,,(BEGIN INTERVIEW)
... 6,T77777777B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,133333333,,INTERVIEWER:  CTVA's your major?
... 7,T88888888B,Male,UNKNOWN,AMC,144444444,,"STUDENT:  Yes, that's right."
... """
>>> fd = StringIO.StringIO(data)
>>> print list(csv.reader(fd))
[['Order', 'LearningID', 'Gender', 'Race', 'College', '  ID ', 'B', 'Transcript Text'], ['1', 'T66666666B', 'Male', 'UNKNOWN', 'AMC', '122333444', '', '(BEGIN INTERVIEW)'], ['6', 'T77777777B', 'Male', 'UNKNOWN', 'AMC', '133333333', '', "INTERVIEWER:  CTVA's your major?"], ['7', 'T88888888B', 'Male', 'UNKNOWN', 'AMC', '144444444', '', "STUDENT:  Yes, that's right."]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following,

```
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip the header row
    for i, row in reader:
        print(i)
        print(row[7])
```

If if this works.